# Parsing season and episode information using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to filename for season and episode information, using `RegEx`. I wnat to handle the special case where there are more than one season in the same file:

Example filename:

```
Defiance.S03E01+E02.Custom.DKSubs.720p.HDTV.x264-NGSerier
```

Sofar I've written this regular Expression:

```
S(?<season>\d{1,2})|E(\d{1,2}){1,}
```

And it gives me the season and the episode list. But the problem is that this patters will also match

```
Defiance.S03E01-E03.Custom.DKSubs.720p.HDTV.x264-NGSerier
```

and

```
Defiance.S03E01E02E03.Custom.DKSubs.720p.HDTV.x264-NGSerier
```

So how do I know if the episode list was seperated with `-` or `+` or nothing?

If it makes any diffrence, then please notice the expression are ot be used in a c# program.

Comment: Someone is making bot downloader ? :-)

Comment: You do not mention how you want to handle these special cases.

Comment: In its own regular Expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex :

`S\d{1,2}([-+]?E\d{1,2})+`

Code :

```
void Main()
{


    Regex regex = new Regex(@"S\d{1,2}([-+]?E\d{1,2})+");
    Match match = regex.Match("Defiance.S03E01E02E03.Custom.DKSubs.720p.HDTV.x264-NGSerier");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
    match = regex.Match("Defiance.S03E01-E03.Custom.DKSubs.720p.HDTV.x264-NGSerier");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
    match = regex.Match("Defiance.S03E01E02E03.Custom.DKSubs.720p.HDTV.x264-NGSerier");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }

}
```

3 results :

```
S03E01E02E03
S03E01-E03
S03E01E02E03
```

`+` can also be used

Edit : After your comment :

Use this regex :

```
(?<season>S\d{1,2})((?<sep>[-+]?)(?<epi>E\d{1,2}))+
```

You can see now :

[image]

Look [**here**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cseason%3ES%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)((%3F%3Csep%3E%5B-%2B%5D%3F)(%3F%3Cepi%3EE%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D))%2B&i=Defiance.S03E01-E03-E04.Custom.DKSubs.720p.HDTV.x264-NGSerier)

Comment: I hope there's no more than 99 episodes :-)

Comment: I cant make it work because form each call to regEx I get two groups: One returning eg S03E01E02E03, and one returning E03.

Perhaps I didn't asked clear enough: From the original expression I got the season and a list of episodes. But I want to know the episode seperator.

Comment: So if you could change [-+] to -,+ or <nothing> and give me the seperator the I'm up and running

Comment: @JensBorrisholt see now